# Can´t submit form content of a jQuery UI modal windows

Tags: form-submit

I like to use the jQuery UI modal dialog, to create new users in a database by using php code. I get the modal code example from the jQuery UI page and the form is opend in the modal window.
The orignal code example just adds the form datas into a table on the page with `/$( "#users tbody" ).append...` and so on.

But I need to submit the form datas to a php file. So far so good. I thought, okay I´ve just to replace the append code part with `$("form#modal-form").submit();` and it´s should be working. But it doesn´t, and I don´t get it why.

I do the modal windows with:

```
dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {

      "Create User": addUser,

      Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      form[ 0 ].reset();
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
      });
```

And the addUser function:

```
function addUser() {
    var valid = true;
    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

    ...validation of the form datas...

    if ( valid ) {
        //$( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
        //  "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
        //  "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
        //  "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        //"</tr>" );
        $("form#modal-form").submit();
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
     }
     return valid;
   }
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="adduser.php" name="modal-form" id="modal-form" method="POST">
<fieldset>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
</fieldset>
```

All I get is the error

> Too much recursion

Where is my mistake? Can anyone maybe help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have it.

When I use the native method with:

```
$("#modal-form")[0].submit();
```

then it works.